# Installing from vitualbox, are partitions and disks safe ?

Tags: virtualbox

That's what I thought until I reached that step in the CentOS installation process : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hdp.jpg

Im using VB on a dual boot windows/ubuntu and from ubuntu. Is it warning me about erasing windows here ? Isn't it installed in the virtual disk created by VB? Did I do something wrong ?...

Comment: No: there are two kinds of partition tables, an older called MS-DOS, and a newer one called GPT. Your virtual disk will still have an MS-DOS-type partition table even after you install on it a completely different operating system. And likewise, for a physical disk. It is called MS-DOS because it was introduced by Microsoft, not because it is hosting a Microsoft operating system. It may, or it may not. In this case, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning concerns the Virtual Disk, not the physical disk.

I imagine you chose both a format and a size for the disk for your VM machine. This is the only disk the install program (you are running it inside VirtualBox, right?) can see, and it is telling you: careful, I see a disk, I will wipe it out. Poor sod ignores that disk is not a previously used disk, just an empty portion of your physical disk, set aside exactly for this purpose.

If you are running the install program within VirtualBox, you may proceed without fear.

Comment: I thought by "MSDOS" it meant he saw my windows installation (in /dev/sda).. Better safe than sorry. Thank you very much.